# AngularJS repeater iterates too many times

Tags: angularjs

So I got this HTML:

```
<body ng-app="pastaApp">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div ng-controller="dataService">
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="post in testAPI">{{post.title}}</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="app.js"></script>
```

And this in my app.js:

```
pastaApp.controller('dataService', function ($scope, $http) {
    $http({
      method: 'GET',
      url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/100'
   }).then(function (success){
        $scope.testAPI = success;
   },function (error){
        //
   });
});
```

And I suspected it to give me one li, but it gave me 5.
It gives me this HTML:

```
<ul>
<!-- ngRepeat: post in testAPI -->
<li ng-repeat="post in testAPI" class="ng-binding ng-scope">at nam consequatur ea labore ea harum</li>
<!-- end ngRepeat: post in testAPI -->
<li ng-repeat="post in testAPI" class="ng-binding ng-scope"></li>
<!-- end ngRepeat: post in testAPI -->
<li ng-repeat="post in testAPI" class="ng-binding ng-scope"></li>
<!-- end ngRepeat: post in testAPI -->
<li ng-repeat="post in testAPI" class="ng-binding ng-scope"></li><!-- end ngRepeat: post in testAPI -->
<li ng-repeat="post in testAPI" class="ng-binding ng-scope"></li>
<!-- end ngRepeat: post in testAPI -->
<li ng-repeat="post in testAPI" class="ng-binding ng-scope"></li>
<!-- end ngRepeat: post in testAPI -->
</ul>
```

I get too many loops.
There might be a simple fix, but I'm new to this.

I've looked at some fixes like ng-class and such, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Thats because your API-Request does not return an array, just one object.

Comment: You might wanna try `$scope.testAPI = [success];` in that case.

Comment: You should mark @Manish Balodia's answer as [accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if it solved your problem ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have assign $scope.testAPI variable a string(success).
Please make it a array of objects to print title.
e.g.
$scope.testAPI = [{title: 'test 1'}, {title: 'test 2'}];

Comment: Thanks!
That worked.

As I said, I'm new to it, and wasn't aware of that. Helped me alot!

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that 'success' is an array. Also you can implement it as [success].